# Windows Phone Error Handling: WCF with BasicHttpBinding and TransportWithMessageCredential

Tags: c#, .net, windows, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF service that works as expected when providing proper credentials.

When I try to consume the service with **wrong credentials**, the service sends an `MessageSecurityException` error as expected, and I receive an error: `"MessageSecurityException was unhandled by user code"`.

I'm not sure how to handle this exception, since it is raised in the `Reference.cs` file that is auto-generated and not really under my control:

References.cs

```
public string EndLogin(System.IAsyncResult result) {
    object[] _args = new object[0];
    string _result = ((string)(base.EndInvoke("Login", _args, result))); //Here is the error raised
    return _result;
}
```

Ideal would be to check if the `service` has accepted the **credentials** instead of relying on an error raised, but have no idea how to check this.

Hope someone can help me, so my App don't have to crash on each wrong login ;)

Web.config : Service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="BiBasicService.SalesMarketingService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="BiBasicService.ISalesMarketingService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

          <!-- To enable custom Role validation -->
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
            <authorizationPolicies>
              <add policyType="BiBasicService.Security.AuthorizationPolicy, BiBasicService" />
            </authorizationPolicies>
          </serviceAuthorization>

          <!-- To enable custom Username and Password validator-->
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="BiBasicService.Security.CustomValidator, BiBasicService"/>
          </serviceCredentials>

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

ServiceReferences.ClientConfig : Client:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISalesMarketingService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://PUBLICDOMAIN/BasicHttp/SalesMarketingService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISalesMarketingService"
                contract="ServiceReference1.ISalesMarketingService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISalesMarketingService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The MessageSecurityException: it's a **binding** error.

Make sure the `binding configuration` on `server side` and `client side` must match.
Please post the `server` side **web.config** and `client` side **web.config**

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the `IErrorHandler` interface, which would allow you to handle the exception at a more “global level”.   The `IErrorHandler` is an extension that allows explicitly control the behavior of the application when an exception is thrown, implement the `IErrorHandler` interface and add it to the Dispatcher’s ErrorHandlers property.  IErrorHandler enables you to explicitly control the SOAP fault generated, decide whether to send it back to the client, and perform associated tasks, such as logging. Error handlers are called in the order in which they were added to the ErrorHandlers property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/07/wcf-extensibility-ierrorhandler.aspx